# Manipulating labels and levels in tbl_regression (gtsummary) with multinom (nnet)

Tags: r, gtsummary, multinomial

It seems the functions for manipulating labels and levels in tbl_regression tables do not work with multinom from the nnet library. Here is reproducable code with the resulting tables. Does anyone have a clue how to get my labels bold and italicized in multinom? Thanks!

```
 library(nnet)
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

# Create a sample data frame
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  y = sample(c(0, 1, 2), 100, replace = TRUE),
  var1 = rnorm(100),
  var2 = rnorm(100),
  var3 = rnorm(100)
)

# Fit a multinomial logistic regression model with nnet
model <- multinom(y ~ var1 + var2 + var3, data = df)

# Create a summary table with tbl_regression
model_tab <- tbl_regression(model, 
                            exponentiate = TRUE) %>% 
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_labels()

model_tab

# Fit a linear regression model
model_2 <- glm(var1 ~ var2 + var3, data = df, family = "gaussian")

# Create a summary table with tbl_regression
model_2_tab <- tbl_regression(model_2) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_labels()

model_2_tab
```

[image][image]

Comment: When I run the code, I get the following warning:  "Multinomial models have a different underlying structure than the models gtsummary was designed for. Other gtsummary functions designed to work with tbl_regression objects may yield unexpected results." I am using `gtsummary` version 1.6.1.

Comment: Yes, I do too. Since multinom logit models are not that rare, I was hoping there is a workaround, if it is a design issue in gtsummary. If not, gtsummary is not really usable for multinom regressions.

Comment: Perhaps it depends on what you want to do with this.  If you want to put it in an html document, then there may be a CSS work around.  The coefficient labels look like this `<td class="gt_row gt_left">var1</td>`, so perhaps you could use some CSS to change the font face of the text within the element.  If your ultimate goal is from something like RMarkdown to PDF, perhaps this wouldn't work as well.

Comment: Ideally I would like to save the tables as an image, but html would also work. I do not know how to use css though. I am just a humble user, not a developer. ;)

Comment: I made an answer that shows the main components of an RMarkdown file that could be rendered to produce what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If an html document is alright, as I suggested in the comments, you can do it with CSS.  In particular, in an RMarkdown document, you would need to put a code chunk that looks like this:

````
```{css echo=FALSE}
td.gt_row.gt_left{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```
````

Then the you could put your code chunk for the table:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
tbl_regression(model, exponentiate = TRUE) %>% 
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_labels()
```
````

and in the rendered html document, the labels would show up in bold and italics:

[image]

For the categorical variables, the text is indented, so you could differentially change the row headings that are indented.  The second block of code in the chunk below sets the indented entries to normal font.

````
```{css echo=FALSE}
td.gt_row.gt_left{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

td.gt_row.gt_left[style*="text-indent: 10px"]{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

```
````

I made `var1` categorical and here's the resulting table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This renders all entries in the left column italicized and bold. In tbl_regression you can distinguish between variable and level labels. (italicize_labels(), italicize_levels()). danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_regression.html Is there a way to distinguish between those using this method? I have categorical predictors where the levels are indented. It would be great to distinguish between variables and levels with bold and italized font.

Comment: You can, I posted an edit to the answer that would allow you to distinguish between the two.